# Filtering categories with custom post-ypes on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm stuck for hours on a problem that I can't find any solution... here is the thing:

I have 4 custom post-types registered on worpress and all of them uses the same categories that I had previously configured. There is no custom category for these post-types. First I want to list these categories, but it have to link to the custom post-type refered in its page.

Eg.: Page-Blog -> Category list itens links to the posts for that category on that post-type (blog, in this case).

I don't know if you understand what I want, but I've already traveled the web on so many sites searching for a solution that I don't even know if it's possible to have one...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cat-post-type/, may it solve your problem

You can select custom post type by categories and tag